# Asset Build with Webpack encore - Error: Problem deleting JS entry for _tmp_copy when using configureFilenames #978

Tags: symfony, webpack, build, assets

Version:

- symfony v5.2.7
- symfony/webpack-encore-bundle        v1.11.2

I want to set the name of my assets with my real version name.

My prefered way would be to use `enableVersioning` and generate the hash myself, but i didn't find how.

The hack i found is by replacing `.enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())` with :

```
    .configureFilenames({
        js: '[name].js?version=' + version,
        css: '[name].css?version=' + version
    })
```

Here is my `webpack.config.js` file

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
// var version = require('./package.json').version;

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    .setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')
    .addEntry('login', './assets/js/scenes/login.js')
    .addEntry('home', './assets/js/scenes/home.js')
    .addEntry('container', './assets/js/scenes/container.js')
    .addEntry('aside', './assets/js/component/containerGroupSelector.js')
    .addEntry('chart', './assets/js/component/containerMeasuresChart.js')
    .addEntry('alerts', './assets/js/scenes/alertsList.js')
    .addEntry('createAlert', './assets/js/scenes/createAlert.js')
    .addEntry('profile', './assets/js/scenes/profile.js')
    .addEntry('sensor', './assets/js/scenes/sensorList.js')
    .addEntry('sensorShow', './assets/js/scenes/sensorShow.js')
    //.addEntry('page2', './assets/page2.js')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    //.splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    //.disableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // .configureFilenames({
    //     js: '[name].js?version=' + version,
    //     css: '[name].css?version=' + version
    // })
    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })
    // refresh browser
    .configureWatchOptions(function(watchOptions) {
        // enable polling and check for changes every 250ms
        // polling is useful when running Encore inside a Virtual Machine

        watchOptions.poll = 250;
    })
    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    .enableSassLoader()

    .copyFiles({
        from: './assets/images',
        to: 'images/[path][name].[ext]',
        pattern: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/
    })
    .copyFiles({
        from: './assets/icon',
        to: 'icon/[path][name].[ext]',
        pattern: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/
    })
    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    //.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    //.autoProvidejQuery()

    // uncomment if you use API Platform Admin (composer req api-admin)
    //.enableReactPreset()
    //.addEntry('admin', './assets/admin.js')
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

If I uncomment `var version = require('./package.json').version;` and replace `enableVersioning` by `configureFilenames` (see above) I get the following error when building assets :

```
panel                     | (node:74) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Problem deleting JS entry for _tmp_copy: 0 files were deleted
panel                     |     at /var/www/panel/node_modules/@symfony/webpack-encore/lib/webpack/delete-unused-entries-js-plugin.js:41:27
panel                     |     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
panel                     |     at emit (/var/www/panel/node_modules/@symfony/webpack-encore/lib/webpack/delete-unused-entries-js-plugin.js:19:28)
panel                     |     at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/var/www/panel/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:65:1)
panel                     |     at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/var/www/panel/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
panel                     |     at Compiler.emitAssets (/var/www/panel/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:491:19)
panel                     |     at onCompiled (/var/www/panel/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:278:9)
panel                     |     at /var/www/panel/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:681:15
panel                     |     at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/var/www/panel/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:4:1)
panel                     |     at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/var/www/panel/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
panel                     |     at /var/www/panel/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:678:31
panel                     |     at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/var/www/panel/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
panel                     |     at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/var/www/panel/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
panel                     |     at /var/www/panel/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1423:35
panel                     |     at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/var/www/panel/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
panel                     |     at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/var/www/panel/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
panel                     |     at /var/www/panel/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1414:32
panel                     |     at eval (eval at create (/var/www/panel/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:17:1)
panel                     | (node:74) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
panel                     | (node:74) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**UPDATE**:
After Upgrading the node package`@symfony/webpack-encore` to 1.3.0, here is the new error message:

```
[webpack-cli] HookWebpackError: Problem deleting JS entry for _tmp_copy: 0 files were deleted ()
    at makeWebpackError (/var/www/panel/node_modules/webpack/lib/HookWebpackError.js:49:9)
    at /var/www/panel/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:2496:12
    at eval (eval at create (/var/www/panel/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:79:1)
    at fn (/var/www/panel/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:427:17)
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/var/www/panel/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:76:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/var/www/panel/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
    at cont (/var/www/panel/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:2493:34)
    at /var/www/panel/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:2539:10
    at /var/www/panel/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830:7
    at Object.each (/var/www/panel/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2850:39)
-- inner error --
Error: Problem deleting JS entry for _tmp_copy: 0 files were deleted ()
    at /var/www/panel/node_modules/@symfony/webpack-encore/lib/webpack/delete-unused-entries-js-plugin.js:49:27
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at deleteEntries (/var/www/panel/node_modules/@symfony/webpack-encore/lib/webpack/delete-unused-entries-js-plugin.js:18:28)
    at /var/www/panel/node_modules/@symfony/webpack-encore/lib/webpack/delete-unused-entries-js-plugin.js:59:17
    at /var/www/panel/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:531:56
    at fn (/var/www/panel/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:425:10)
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/var/www/panel/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:76:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/var/www/panel/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
    at cont (/var/www/panel/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:2493:34)
    at /var/www/panel/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:2539:10
caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
Error: Problem deleting JS entry for _tmp_copy: 0 files were deleted ()
    at /var/www/panel/node_modules/@symfony/webpack-encore/lib/webpack/delete-unused-entries-js-plugin.js:49:27
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at deleteEntries (/var/www/panel/node_modules/@symfony/webpack-encore/lib/webpack/delete-unused-entries-js-plugin.js:18:28)
    at /var/www/panel/node_modules/@symfony/webpack-encore/lib/webpack/delete-unused-entries-js-plugin.js:59:17
    at /var/www/panel/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:531:56
    at fn (/var/www/panel/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:425:10)
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/var/www/panel/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:76:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/var/www/panel/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
    at cont (/var/www/panel/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:2493:34)
    at /var/www/panel/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:2539:10
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: What encore version are you using? Try updating to the latest version, since there was some kind of bug with [`copyFiles`](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/pull/930).

Comment: it is the `v1.11.2`, i think it's the last one ?

Comment: And the node package? At least the config looks pre-1.0, as there's no stimulus stuff. Upgrading to `1.3.0` works for me, you can try refreshing the recipes to bring in the new files and configs with `composer recipes:install symfony/webpack-encore-bundle --force`.

Comment: @msg I updated my answer with new error message after upgrade

Comment: Composer should create the bundle yaml configuration, along with a bunch of `.js` for stimulus and an updated `webpack.config.js`, maybe you have an old flex package? Anyways, I did replicate your problem with `0.30.2` and updating solved it, I don't think I can offer any more help. Since the bug I mentioned involved `copyFiles`, I'd try commenting those sections to try to isolate the problem and confirm if it's caused by that plugin or there's something else going on.